# Two buttons (with a fixed width/height and fixed position) with JFrame

Tags: java, button, jframe

I want to preface that yes, this is a homework question.

We are told to create two buttons that increment their own individual counters. The counter part is done in another class not shown here.

I first create a new `JFrame` and two buttons with their own text.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me too!");
```

I set their bounds.

```
button1.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
button2.setBounds(0, 50, 100, 50);
```

Adding these buttons onto the frame.

```
frame.add(button1);
frame.add(button2);
```

Attach their individual action listeners (since they each increment their own counter).

```
ActionListener listener = new ClickListener();
ActionListener listener2 = new ClickListener();
button1.addActionListener(listener);
button2.addActionListener(listener2);
```

Set the frame size and misc settings.

```
frame.setSize(100, 100);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

With that said, this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, `button1` is behind `button2` despite the hardcoded `.setBound` properties.

I have tried changing different settings for `button2.setBounds(..)`, but it seems nothing I put in actually changes its position or size. Changing the inputs into `button1`, however, changes its position/size.

What gives?

Comment: Don't use `setBounds`, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you don't font such things as fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines are other elements which will effect how much space a given component may need to be rendered properly, instead, make use of an appropriate layout manager, like `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid use of `setBounds(...)` and null layout as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

Instead if you want one JButton on top of the other and that they be equal sides, why not simply use a `GridLayout(0, 1)`?

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html I am very much with using more modern and less.. hardcoded ways to do things, but unfortunately, this is a school assignment, and we were given templated code. It's unfortunate, but it's something all CS students much go through v.v

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: yes, that is what I'm suggesting. What **exactly** are the restrictions and templates you've been given?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I simply added a GridLayout constructor. Thanks a lot Eels!

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.add(button1);
frame.add(button2);
```

JFrame has `BroderLayout` as default and `add()` methods adds the component in the CENTER by default. i.e you are adding two buttons at the same location. Use overloaded `add()` method along with location for e.g.:

```
frame.add(button1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Or you can use a `JPanel`. add the buttons on panel first then add the panel on `JFrame`.

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(button2);

frame.add(panel);
```

You can set the alignment of buttons also

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
```

or you can define a horizontal/vertical gap between them.

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,10,10));
```

**Finally for more info read about [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) where you will find the samples.**

Answer (score 1):

See you have two buttons namely `Button1` and `Button 2` so if you are using setbound property then use using absolute positioning to place controls over the frame like this way.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container Pane = getContentPane();
Pane.setLayout(null);

JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me too!");

Pane.add(Button1);
Pane.add(Button2);

Insets insets = Pane.getInsets();
Dimension size = Button1.getPreferredSize();
Button1.setBounds(10 + insets.left, 10 + insets.top,size.width, size.height); //use your own constants

size = Button2.getPreferredSize();
Button2.setBounds(75 + insets.left, 5 + insets.top,size.width, size.height + 8);
```

Try avoid using this as it will only make your code lengthy instead use java built in layout like FlowLayout, BorderLayout,GridBagLayout etc. Find more detail here [Layout Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container Pane = getContentPane();
Pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!");
JButton button2 = new JButton("Click me too!");

Pane.add(Button1);
Pane.add(Button2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default layout manager for a JFrame is BorderLayout, and a component is by default added to BorderLayout.CENTER if none is specified. Since they are both being added to the center one is covering up the other. You either need to specify the location on the frame for one of them or use a different layout manager.

Also (and this is not related to the question) You can use the same listener for both buttons, you can use an if statement to check where the event came from and process it differently based on that.